# Trying to repair avon roadster 2000 circa

Tags: repair, identify-this-bike

Looking for a Manual or pictures to help put back together an Avon roadster circa 2000.[image]

Comment: You might need to ask specific questions about a part that is not working as-expected.  For a start, that's unlikely to be a 2000's replica.  The cottered pedal cranks suggest 1970s at the newest, and possibly older.   The rear brake under the chainstay looks too shiny, as do the rims.   What is wrong with it ?

Comment: @Criggie they still make them like this for the retro enthusiast.

Comment: @JoeK true, but generally not with cottered cranks.  I have seen a modern reproduction with rod brakes.

Comment: @Criggie have a look at what the Indian bike polo team ride. The cotter pin is only dead in the west.

Comment: It's a generic bike, built in 1970s style with cottered cranks, etc.  The brakes are the only "odd" thing, to a US observer.  If it is really ca 2000, though, it's hard to predict whether there might be cartridge bearings, etc.  But if you really need to "put it back together" you can start with any 1970s assembly manual for a regular "city" bike (vs racing or touring).

Answer (score 8):

You do not need a special manual and there probably isn't any. You have to identify the kind of parts that are used on the bike. Like: quill stem, coaster brake rear hub, the type of bottom bracket (square taper) and so on.

Most skills you need for this bike are the same as on any other similar bike from older times so you need to get generc knowledge about bike maintenance - directed to older bikes specfically.

There are many resources you can use, books, vdeo tutorials, the Sheldon Brown's website. There are specific questions and answers here that list such resources.

Answer (score 2):

As Vladimir says specific questions for issues will generate more detailed information. The problem is if you don't know what to ask for it's hard to know what to look for. Here is some information to get you started.

Here is a diagram of a bike like - but not exactly the same as - your bike.

[image]

Parts List
[image]
[Sheldon Brown](https://sheldonbrown.com/retroraleighs/catalogs/1977-drawings/index.html)

Here is the link to the [manufacturer's page for speedsters](https://www.avoncycles.com/roadsters-bicycles) where you can still buy a brand new bike similar to this one. Contacting them might produce information on repair documents or parts availability.

search web or YouTube for

- "rod brakes" for brake adjustment.
- "cottered cranks"